# Modelica special operators source code

Tags: modelica

As the example below:

```
model HelloWorld "A Simple Model"
  Real x(start = 1);
equation 
  **der(x) = -x;**
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2")));
end HelloWorld;
```

I planned to write some code transforming `Modelica` source into java format. But, I can not find the source code of special operators like `der()` and so on.

I mean: the example in java can be written into this format:

```
class HelloWorld{
   ModelicaReal x = new ModelicaReal(start,1);

   public void run(){
      while(time...){
         ...der(x)... 
      }
   }
}
```

I want to process `der(x)` as a java function call. But I must find the `der()` operator source code first, then I can transform the `der()` operator into a java function. But `Modelica` operators source code are not in `Modelica` standard library?

Answer (score 3):

There is no source code for `der()`. (*At least not like the one you are looking for.*)

Why?

Because it is (*you said it*) an **operator**. Not a function. What you are asking is something (*almost*) like the source code for the `+` operator or `connect`.

I am sure you have come across functions like that in `java`. For example in `C++` you have `sizeof()`. Which is not really a function but looks and acts like one.

`der()` is implemented by each simulator's integration method. And provided for you as a built-in operator. It is not implemented as a library function like `sin`, `cos`.... And quite frankly it can't be. It is not evaluated as you see it in the source code.

I am not sure how you would go about translating it. But there are some *ode solvers* and *integrators* out there. I hope some one will soon give you an alternative approach.

---

Just a friendly heads up, It might not be as easy as you are approaching it now. And you can't translate `modelica` code (*for that matter any source code*) to another language line by line like that. Maybe that's OK for translating `java` to `C/C++` or vice versa, but those languages are closely related and used for the same kind of programming paradigm. `Modelica` is different.

**It is easier if you stick to translating the `algorithmic` parts of `modelica` and leave `equations` out of it for now. Then you can go ahead with the current approach.**

Good luck.

Comment: Appreciated for your detail answer? And If so, May I call Modelica Operator from Java through some methods? If there any method like this?
Is it possible through OMC or some scripts?

Comment: For Dymola there are API as Java methods to use to invoke Dymola, compile a model and get the results, maybe there is somenthing similar with OMC. The real problem is that you cannot adress the problem line by line, but you have to sort all the equations of a model before compiling and than apply your integrators and ODE solvers.

Comment: @xing See Marcos comment. I think OMC also have a similar java interface. check this. http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/043/020/ecp09430121.pdf and also you can always ask on the formus. Here is a similar question. https://www.openmodelica.org/index.php/forum/topic?id=51